# Listing pyramid template files from a view

Tags: python, templates, pyramid, chameleon

I want to make some of my templates user editable inside my web app (the actual template, not just replacing content via replacement variables). But I can't figure out how to get a list of template files.

Obviously if I know the real path I can just us regular python tools. But is there a way to get the actual file location with the `some.package:templates/template.pt` syntax?

I want to get a list of template files in, let's say `some.package:templates/email/`. Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

To go from a dotted asset specification you may use `pyramid.path.AssetResolver`, as the [documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/path.html) states, it looks like this:

```
from pyramid.path import AssetResolver

a = AssetResolver()
resolver = a.resolve('myproject:templates/foo.pt')
print(resolver.abspath())
# -> /path/to/myproject/templates/foo.pt
```

Specifically it has this to say about resolving paths:

> If spec is an absolute filename (e.g. `/path/to/myproject/templates/foo.pt`) or an absolute asset spec (e.g. `myproject:templates/foo.pt`), an asset descriptor is returned without taking into account the package passed to this class' constructor.

---

However I would highly recommend against letting users modify the template files inside your package directly. What I would recommend instead is that you in your installation procedures have a way of copying all your templates out of your package, and then using [Pyramids asset override](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/assets.html#overriding-assets) mechanism to sub out the existing asset specs with a new location. At that point you can use the standard Python open/close file methods to have the user update the templates.